# Add word document and keep formatting

Tags: vba, formatting, ms-word

I am attempting to add my CV to the end of a document. The following code does just that but the formatting of the CV is messed up once it is inserted into the new document. Can I insert the file and keep the original formatting of the CV (I dont want to copy and paste from an open document):

```
objword1.Selection.InsertFile Filename:=cv1Address, _
    ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False
```

Comment: Why not record a macro to reformat the imported file/cv and then copy/paste this macro into your code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you can't use the InsertFile-method but have to open the file and copy&paste with `wdFormatOriginalFormatting`

I have found this:

```
Set rtffile = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="C:\temp\rtf_stapler_problem\concat\cars2.rtf", ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
wdApp.Selection.WholeStory
wdApp.Selection.Copy
wdApp.ActiveWindow.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
destdoc.Activate
wdApp.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
wdApp.Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
```

[here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/05ddc564-a669-4822-8bab-311119c76362/method-pasteandformat-with-wdformatoriginalformatting-stripping-rtf-formatting?forum=worddev)